# "This is not getting washed" What is the function of "getting" in the sentence

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, progressive-aspect, grammatical-roles, get-passive

I have seen a few sentences where the structure looks like this subject + to be + verb-ing + verb in past. Is this grammatically correct?

Answer (score 3):

Normally in English, the passive is formed using the verb *to be* followed by the past participle of the main verb.  But sometimes the passive can be formed using the verb *to get* followed by the past participle of the main verb.  See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_passive_voice)

(active) Tom washes this.
(passive) This is washed (by Tom).
-or-
(passive) This gets washed (by Tom).
(progressive passive) This is getting washed.
(negation of progressive passive) This is not getting washed.

Comment: Standard English does not, but some dialects of English have more of these...  "This needs washed."

Answer (score 1):

The word *getting* in that example means the same as *being*, and it puts the sentence into passive voice in continuous tense.

Consider:

Ephraim is not washing the car. (active voice)

The car is not getting/being washed by Ephraim.  (passive voice with mention of actor)

The car is not getting/being washed. (passive voice, with no mention of who should be washing it.)

The word *getting* has a slightly different flavor than *being*, at least to me.
*Being* focuses on the process of the washing, while *getting* focuses on the result, that is, a washed car.

For example, *the car was washed* doesn't imply that it got clean, but *the car got washed* does.

Comment: It could also mean “going to get”

Comment: That's true. "You need to wash the car!"..."The cars not getting washed, unless you pay in advance!". But that's a more remote possibility.

Answer (score -2):

I take it that's "I have (seen a few sentences where the structure looks like this subject + to be + verb-ing + verb) in past" rather than "I have seen a few sentences where the structure looks like this subject + to be + verb-ing + (verb in past)"?

"getting" is present participle and "washed" is past participle. The function of "getting" is subject complement, and the function of "washed" is object of "getting". "getting" and "washed" together form a participial phrase.

Comment: Saying that "washed" (a past participle, as you note) functions as an object is problematic for those who prefer to restrict objects to nominals (nouns, pronouns, gerunds, etc.). There are other roles that could be assigned to it (e.g., predicate adjective).

Comment: Throwing around grammar terms without defining them, or giving any reasoning for their application, is rarely useful. Also, this does not answer the question - is this a grammatically correct construction?

Comment: @DW256 The question asked what the function is. If the OP finds it not useful to be told what the functions are, they shouldn't ask that. You comment is bizarre.